# Is this sentence correct: I could not keep calm?

Tags: phrases, synonyms

How can I say when I know that I do something badly, but I can't keep calm.

E.G. - She asked me don't tell you, but I couldn't ...

I hope you understand what I meant. :)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU!  You may want to check out our sister site, [ell.stackexchange.com.](http://ell.stackexchange.com)  It is intended for people who are trying to learn English as a second language.

Answer (score 1):

You could use "I can't/couldn't contain myself".

Also, your sentence can be improved to make more sense, as thus:

"She asked me not to tell you, but I couldn't (contain myself)"

Is this what you mean? That she asked me to not say anything, but I couldn't keep myself from saying it, so I just had to say it?

Comment: Yes, this is . thank you. but can you say what is difference between  (or among: ) : "I couldn't contain myself" I"I couldn't keep it to myself" and "I couldn't keep the calm".
which is more  informal?

Comment: "I couldn't contain myself" refers to the fact that you could not keep your eagerness within yourself, and it had to 'burst out'.

"I couldn't keep it to myself" is very similar, meaning I couldn't keep it a secret, I had to let it out and tell someone.

"I couldn't keep calm" is not something I would personally use, it is more like saying "I couldn't stay relaxed about it (maybe I was nervous about it)

I think they are all pretty much in par with each other, but either "I couldn't keep calm" (if this is the correct context for you) or "I couldn't keep it to myself" would be most informal.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to know how to describe a situation where you have done something wrong and you cannot keep it to yourself (keep it a secret, or keep quiet, or keep it quiet).

Based on your example, you should say:

> She asked me not to tell you but I couldn't keep it from you.

It means someone asked you not to mention your "bad" deed to your partner (or friend or mother), but you really don't want to keep it a secret.  You'd feel better to let it out to this person.

Hope my assumption of your question is correct :-)

Feel free to comment on it if this isn't related to what you wanted to ask.

**Note:**

- To do something bad = To do something that is not good
- To do something badly = To do something not so well
- To badly want to do something = To really want to do something

Also, please take a look at the Stack Exchange site for English Learners (https://ell.stackexchange.com/), which is a really good resource for learning and improving your skills in English as a second language.

Comment: I didn't mean this but it will be useful, in future:) 
My example was bad, I know. And my English too:)
thank you very much.

Comment: @MariamJikia, sorry for my assumption.  Glad that it was useful.  Don't worry about your English; practice will make it perfect.  You   seem to have confidence.  That's all that matters.  Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

I saw just people saying "I will not keep calm."

But I don't see anything wrong in your sentence.

I saw too:

"I Couldn't Keep It to Myself"
or "keep the calm"

"I could not keep the calm.", this sounds more natural I think or "I don't know if
I will keep calm."

Macmillan Grammar says that that "will" must be used with things we are not sure, so I think the "will" sounds like a possibilibity and not like something going to happening.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
But can you say what is difference between (or among: ) : "I couldn't contain myself" I"I couldn't keep it to myself" and "I couldn't keep the calm". which is more informal?

Comment: I really don't know, so, just my opinion:
"I couldn't keep the calm"  and "I couldn't contain myself"  sounds more informal.
 "I couldn't contain myself" it's clear that you becontained or not, just this.
I"I couldn't keep it to myself", I don't know if it's possible will+could.
The third one sounds like the first.

I'm not sure, waiting for grammar people, I'm just based on the speaking or texts I saw.

Good luck with your question ^^